# A Problem about Integral and Infinite-Term Summation.

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

Before narrating my problem, please let me recall the consensus of Riemannian integral condensely: The section $[a,b]$, on which a function $f(x)$ is defined, can be separated into many smaller sections like
$$a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b.$$
Then the Riemannian sum
$$\sigma=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_k)\Delta x_k,\qquad \xi_k\in[x_k,x_{k+1})$$
becomes integral of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ when $\max(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\max\Delta x_k\rightarrow0$.

Clearly, We can only separates the section into integer many smaller sections. If we take a set $A$ whose elements are each smaller sections devided from $[a,b]$, then the cardinal number of this set (and then the number of smaller sections) is at most $\aleph$, equal to the cardinal number of $\mathbb Z$.

However, for an integral $\int_a^bf(x){\rm d}x$, $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in[a,b]$, since $[a,b]$ is a continuum with cardinal number $\aleph_0>\aleph$, there are also $\aleph_0$ of $f(x){\rm d}x$'s to be summed.

How can the sum of $\aleph$ terms fully describe the sum of $\aleph_0$ terms and vice versa? Or what is the relation between an integral $\int_a^bf(x){\rm d}x$ and an infinite term sum $\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)({\rm for\ all}\ x\in[a,b])$?

---

Background of this problem: I'm still trying to generalize a fractal derivative.
I hope to generalize harmonic polynomials to fractal power, i.e. if there exists a k-homogeneous polynomial
$$p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n}{x_1}^{\alpha_1}{x_2}^{\alpha_2}...{x_n}^{\alpha_n},\qquad \sum_i\alpha_i=k\in\mathbb R\ {\rm or\ even}\ \mathbb C$$
such that
$$\Delta p=0.$$

Then I began to thinking about its simplest appearance: could a function be expanded in the form as
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i, \qquad i\in[0,+\infty) $$
I have tacitly let that $x^i$ is already defined for all $i\in\mathbb R$ , and hence the term of this summation, or the "cardinary number" might be $\aleph_0$ (is it?).
Commom method to expand a function, however, just uses integers, like
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,\qquad i\in\mathbb Z$$
and its term is "$\aleph$".
I found that it's difficult to put a fractal expansion $\sum a_ix^i$ ino an integral $\int a_ix^i$, and then began to consider what is the difference between integral and infinite-term summation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general that data doesn't fully describe the integral. When studying theories of integration one restricts the set of functions to the ones that can be integrated, in that the limit you described exists. One way to do this for the Riemann integral is to define step functions, which take the form
$$
\varphi = \sum_{i = 1}^N \alpha_i\chi_{[a_i, b_i]}
$$
where $\chi_X$ takes the value $1$ on $X$ and $0$ elsewhere. The integral of this function is directly computable as
$$
\int \varphi = \sum \alpha_i (b_i - a_i)
$$
Then you restrict the integration theory to the functions $f$ such that
$$
\sup\left\{\left.\int \varphi \right| \varphi < f \ \forall x\right\} = \inf\left\{\left.\int \varphi \right| \varphi > f \ \forall x\right\}.
$$
and you prove that most functions that you want to integrate satisfy this. For example, continuous functions are integrable in this sense. An example of a non integrable function is $\chi_{\mathbb Q \cap [0, 1]}$ - in the above the infimum is 0 and the supremum is 1.

By only looking at integrable functions you are reducing the data needed to describe your functions, and these restrictions can be thought of approximately in terms of continuity - you want to be able get information about the values of an integrable function at a point by looking at values near that point, and this resolves your issue. More sophisticated theories of integration (eg Lebesgue) lead to less restrictive definitions on the functions.

The infinite sum $\sum_a^bf(x)$ doesn't really make much sense because if $f$ is nonzero on some interval $[c, d] \subseteq [a, b]$ this sum is going to be undefined / very $\infty$. One approach to get around this is to weight the contribution from each $f(x), x \in [a, b]$ by some infinitesimal value, which is how integrals are defined using measure theory.

Comment: Appreciates for your answer. You did inspire me. Maybe trying to integralize a summation  indeed nead more restriction.  At present I had batter concentrate on the summation, such like the problem: noticing that $\exp x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, what is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for $k\in[0,+\infty)$... I hope this form may relates to $\Gamma(x)$ or other non-elementary functons.